# Draw stroke characters with outlines in openGL

Tags: opengl, fonts

I am using openGL to draw fonts.  My fonts need to be rotatable and I cannot use glut, so I created a static class that has vertex lists for every needed character.  I then render these using GL_LINE_STRIP.

Recently I've been asked to allow my characters to have outlines, sort of like they would if you went into word, created a bold character and then under Font, gave it an outline.
Not sure how to put a picture of that in stack overflow.

I was wondering if there was a way to do that given my current method of drawing characters using lines.  Is it possible to have a line border, or is that inherently nonsense?

Answer (score 2):

Two passes:

```
const float OUTLINE_WIDTH = 3.0f;
const float INNER_WIDTH = 1.0f;

glLineWidth( OUTLINE_WIDTH );
glColor3ub( outline.r, outline.g, outline.b );
DrawText();

glLineWidth( INNER_WIDTH );
glColor3ub( inner.r, inner.g, inner.b );
DrawText();
```